# Cannot open Android studio 4.2 Canary 8 or 9 after having installed Canary 7

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.2

Context : 
macOs Catalina 10.15.6
Java 1.8.0_161

After having updated Android Studio 4.2 Canary 7 to Canary 8 (and to Canary 9), it cannot be opened any more.

I've tried installing it from both Android Studio official website and from JetBrains' Toolbox app. In any case the same behavior occurs : 
When trying to launch Android Studio nothing happens. It doesn't even show the "SplashScreen" thing.

When using command line to launch the app I have an error that may be useful :

```
> open [...]/Android\ Studio\ 4.2\ Preview.app

LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file [...]/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app.
```

I've seen on the internet that it may mean that the app haven't the appropriate permissions to be launched. With previous versions of Android Studio canary, i've never changed any permissions so why now ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When launching directly  `[...]/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app/Contents/MacOs/studio` I have the following output :

```
2020-09-03 14:09:02.078 studio[4589:59392] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2020-09-03 14:09:02.078 studio[4589:59392] Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist: /Applications/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app/Contents/jbr
2020-09-03 14:09:02.078 studio[4589:59392] Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist: /Applications/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app/Contents/jdk
2020-09-03 14:09:02.082 studio[4589:59397] WorkingDirectory is absent in Info.plist. Current Directory: /Applications
2020-09-03 14:09:02.082 studio[4589:59397] fullFileName is: /Applications/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2020-09-03 14:09:02.082 studio[4589:59397] fullFileName exists: /Applications/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2020-09-03 14:09:02.083 studio[4589:59397] Value of STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2020-09-03 14:09:02.083 studio[4589:59397] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/Android Studio 4.2 Preview.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2020-09-03 14:09:02.083 studio[4589:59397] Done
2020-09-03 14:09:02.083 studio[4589:59397] Processing VMOptions file at /Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.2/studio.vmoptions
2020-09-03 14:09:02.083 studio[4589:59397] Done
2020-09-03 14:09:02.083 studio[4589:59397] Processing VMOptions file at
2020-09-03 14:09:02.084 studio[4589:59397] No content found
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Multiple garbage collectors selected
```

The line i want to highlight here is

```
2020-09-03 14:09:02.083 studio[4589:59397] Processing VMOptions file at /Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioPreview4.2/studio.vmoptions
```

After having removed that file, the new version of canary can be opened !

I guess there is something wrong in this file that prevents the migration

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I've isolated a couple of studio.vmoptions values that, if left in, prevent any version >= Android Studio 4.2 canary 8 to launch.

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-Xloggc:gc.log
```

If I remove all of them, it opens as normal. If I leave any of them, it won't open.

Comment: Same problem in canary 15, had to remove `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`. The other ones were not present any more

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I **hacked** my way around it by providing the app a "jbr" folder.

It used to complain and one error/warning (as stated in the original question) was:

> Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist:
> /Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jbr

So I got in `/Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents` and copied the `jre` folder into a `jbr` one...

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio\ Preview.app/Contents
cp -r jre jbr
```

I don't understand why this preview version would be packaged without the tools it is supposed to need, but, well, it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that  there's bug in this Android Studio build.