# Unable to start Android Studio after upgrade

Tags: macos, android-studio

After upgrading Android Studio to 4.1.2 on macOs I'm unable to start it. It tries to initialize itself but crashes shortly after that with the following stack:

```
    allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2021-02-01 22:50:53.573 studio[3796:311854] Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr
2021-02-01 22:50:53.573 studio[3796:311854] Can't find bundled java.The folder doesn't exist: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jdk
2021-02-01 22:50:53.593 studio[3796:311863] WorkingDirectory is absent in Info.plist. Current Directory: /Users/Admin
2021-02-01 22:50:53.593 studio[3796:311863] fullFileName is: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2021-02-01 22:50:53.593 studio[3796:311863] fullFileName exists: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2021-02-01 22:50:53.593 studio[3796:311863] Value of STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2021-02-01 22:50:53.593 studio[3796:311863] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
2021-02-01 22:50:53.594 studio[3796:311863] Done
2021-02-01 22:50:53.594 studio[3796:311863] Processing VMOptions file at /Users/Admin/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/studio.vmoptions
2021-02-01 22:50:53.596 studio[3796:311863] No content found
2021-02-01 22:50:53.596 studio[3796:311863] Processing VMOptions file at 
2021-02-01 22:50:53.596 studio[3796:311863] No content found
2021-02-01 22:50:58,672 [   3546]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Conflicting component name 'UsagesStatistic': class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent and class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent (componentManager=Application (containerState=ACTIVE) ) 
java.lang.Throwable: Conflicting component name 'UsagesStatistic': class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent and class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent (componentManager=Application (containerState=ACTIVE) )
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:146)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.doAddComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:352)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initPersistenceStateComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:137)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:103)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.initComponent(ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.kt:50)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.initializeComponent$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:358)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createLightService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:598)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getOrCreateLightService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:486)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getLightService$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:458)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:401)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:394)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:20)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.getInstance(UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.java:54)
    at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.ConsentOptions.saveConfirmedConsents(ConsentOptions.java:238)
    at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.ConsentOptions.setSendingUsageStatsAllowed(ConsentOptions.java:138)
    at com.intellij.ide.gdpr.ConsentOptionsProviderImpl.setSendingUsageStatsAllowed(ConsentOptionsProviderImpl.java:14)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.loadState(UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.java:74)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.loadState(UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.java:26)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.doInitComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:438)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:373)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initPersistenceStateComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:138)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.kt:103)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.initComponent(ComponentStoreWithExtraComponents.kt:50)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.initializeComponent$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:358)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createLightService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:598)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getOrCreateLightService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:486)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getLightService$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:458)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doGetService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:401)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.getService(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:394)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:20)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.getInstance(UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent.java:54)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.utils.StatisticsUploadAssistant.isCollectAllowed(StatisticsUploadAssistant.java:43)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.fus.FeatureUsageEventLoggerProvider.isRecordEnabled(FeatureUsageEventLoggerProvider.kt:12)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.StatisticsEventLoggerProvider.createLogger(StatisticsEventLogger.kt:41)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.StatisticsEventLoggerProvider.access$createLogger(StatisticsEventLogger.kt:23)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.StatisticsEventLoggerProvider$logger$2.invoke(StatisticsEventLogger.kt:27)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.StatisticsEventLoggerProvider$logger$2.invoke(StatisticsEventLogger.kt:23)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.StatisticsEventLoggerProvider.getLogger(StatisticsEventLogger.kt)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.fus.FeatureUsageLogger.isEnabled(FeatureUsageLogger.kt:85)
    at com.intellij.internal.statistic.eventLog.fus.FeatureUsageLogger.<clinit>(FeatureUsageLogger.kt:29)
    at com.intellij.configurationStore.statistic.eventLog.FeatureUsageSettingsEvents$logDefaultConfigurationState$1.run(FeatureUsageSettingsEvents.kt:38)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:201)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:193)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-02-01 22:50:58,694 [   3568]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Android Studio 4.1.2  Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7042882 
2021-02-01 22:50:58,694 [   3568]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_242-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2021-02-01 22:50:58,694 [   3568]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - OS: Mac OS X 
2021-02-01 22:50:58,716 [   3590]  ERROR - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Conflicting component name 'UsagesStatistic': class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent and class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent (componentManager=Application (containerState=ACTIVE) ) 
java.lang.Throwable: Conflicting component name 'UsagesStatistic': class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent and class com.intellij.internal.statistic.persistence.UsageStatisticsPersistenceComponent (componentManager=Application (containerState=ACTIVE) )
```

I tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723196/cannot-open-android-studio-4-2-canary-8-or-9-after-having-installed-canary-7), but none of them worked for me.

If there's no direct solution, would complete removal of Android Studio (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)) with following 'clean' install be reasonable approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I had the same error when upgrading my Mac to Big Sur. I tried cleaning it but it did not work so uninstalled Android Studio and all emulators. After re-install, worked perfectly.